# Docker versus Docker-compose with dockerignore

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Are docker and docker-compose supposed to differ in their handling of .dockerignore?

I've got a Docker container which builds fine when I build it directly, e.g. via `docker build -t mycontainer ./mycontainer`, but it fails when I build it via `docker-compose up`. Relevant portion of the `docker-compose.yml` is

```
version: '3'
services:
  mycontainer:
    build: ./mycontainer
  ports:
    - "1234:1234"
  expose:
    - "1234"
```

By using `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash 240e1a06c8f5`, where `240e1a06c8f5` is the last image before the build failure, I found that one of the files, `./mycontainer/mymodel/labels.rdata`, wasn't being copied over by `docker-compose up`, but is copied by `docker build`. It's also *close* to a pattern in the `.dockerignore`, `*/*.RData`.

Is this a difference between case-sensitivity in `.dockerignore` between docker-compose and docker build? Is it a difference in path handling? Is this a known bug? (or intended?)
Versions on MacOs:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried using a case-insensitive `.dockerignore` entry on Windows and it did actually ignore the file, so it looks like your `*/*.RData` will actually ignore your `./mycontainer/mymodel/labels.rdata` file.

Try changing the extension of the file or changing the ignore entry.  I'd change the filename, since that seems like the one-off here.

**EDIT**: This does sound like a bug.  I'd file one on their [Github Issues](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues) page since [I don't see one there already](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues?q=is%3Aissue+dockerignore+sensitivity+is%3Aopen)

Comment: In a similar vein, a coworker suggested adding a !**/features_labels.rdata at the end of the `.dockerignore`. Both that and your suggestion are good workarounds... I was hoping for an explanation of why the behavior differs between `docker build` and `docker-compose build`... Seems like a bug to me